# Strings with space in between

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008

I need a query to get string with space in between.

i.e it should not return strings like

```
' abc', 'abc ' and ' abc '
```

and it should return strings like

```
'ab c' ,' ab c', 'ab c ' and ' ab c '
```

i tried with below query.

```
select user_fname,user_lname
from user where user_fname like '% %';
```

but it is returning all the rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%` matches [*zero* or more characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). I'd suggest adding some `_`s in:

```
select user_fname,user_lname
from user where user_fname like '%_ _%';
```

If that's still matching too much, perhaps:

```
select user_fname,user_lname
from user where user_fname like '%[^ ] [^ ]%';
```

Which will match zero or more characters, then something that definitely isn't a space, a space, something that definitely isn't a space and then zero or more characters.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_fname,user_lname
FROM user 
WHERE user_fname LIKE '% %' AND user_fname NOT LIKE ' %' AND user_fname NOT LIKE '% '
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this also

```
select user_fname,user_lname
from user lTrim(rTrim(user_fname)) LIKE '% %'
```

this will remove the white space left and right of user_fname and then it will try to find the white space between the character.